# Das Possessivpronomen mit Genitiv

Tags: genitive

I found 2 examples of Possessivpronomen sentences, both are from a grammar book but the second sentence does not seem to be right.

1) Wem gehört dieses Buch? Ist es **Ihres**, Frau Schmidt? Ja, es ist **meines**.

2) Gehört dieses Fotoalbum Monika? Ja, das ist **ihr** Album.

Why there is no Genitiv in the second sentence(ihres) while there is in the first one? Is it correct?

Comment: Alan, perhaps a useful thought: don't confuse the possessive pronoun with the possessive case. Both indicate possession, and accordingly, you use either one or the other to express one level of possession. The only instance when it makes sens to use both is if you have two such levels: Yes, it's her suitcase's lid (the lid that belongs to the suitcase that belongs to her) = ...der Deckel ihres Koffers. As you can see, the possessive pronoun (which beaves as an article here) takes the same case as the noun. But I'd forget about this quickly, because it's such a rare occurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no genitive pronoun whatsoever in your sentences.

1) Wem gehört dieses Buch? Ist es Ihres, Frau Schmidt? Ja, es ist meines.

Here the pronouns are "ihres" und "meines", they are in the nominative case. Note that you may sometimes find "ihrs"/"meins" instead of "ihres"/"meines". I *think* both forms are fine when used as stand-alone pronouns, though I wouldn't bet on it.

2) Gehört dieses Fotoalbum Monika? Ja, das ist ihr Album.

And this is a normal sentence in the nominative, the possessive is a determiner (or article) and not a pronoun, so it follows the usual declension for neuter words: ihr Album. To use the pronoun, you could say:

3) Gehört dieses Fotoalbum Monika? Ja, das ist ihr(e)s.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not correct. "Ihres" is masculine and neutrum genitive. For nominative it'd be "ihr". The respective question is "Wessen Buch ist das?" Genitive for sure.

Comment: I see no "wessen Buch ist das" question in the OP. And no, here "ihres" is a neuter pronoun, if it were masculine it would be "ihrer"/"meiner": "Ist dieser Wagen ihrer, Frau Schmidt? Ja, er ist meiner."

Comment: And I don't see a "nominative"-question! "Von wem[dative] ist das Buch? - Es ist von ihr[dative]" -- "Wessen[genitive] Buch ist das? - Es ist ihres[genitive" -- You can answer a dative question with genitive and genitive with dative. But you know that, don't you? – I said "ihres" is masculine **and** neutrum **genitive**. In that very example it's neutrum, yes, I don't care. My point is, it's never nominative.

Comment: I've never talked about the questions, and neither did the OP. The answers to those questions can stand alone as sentences on their own.

Comment: How so? "Es ist ihres". In which case is "ihres", please?

Comment: @karoshi In the same case Maria is in the sentence "Es ist Marias", namely genitive.

Comment: I think there's a difference there, since "Marias" does not change: the object can be masculine, feminine or neuter and it's always "Marias". But if you use the *pronoun*, which, I repeat, "Marias" is not, then it DOES change: "er ist ihrer", "sie ist ihre", "es ist ihres" (and all the last three are nominative).

Comment: @Em1 and c.p.: Sorry, but you're on the wrong track here... If you were talking about a possessive article (possessive adjective for those who prefer that expression) you'd be right: "ihres Buches" is def. genitive. But here we're talking *possessive pronoun*. Just replace "Buch" with "Koffer" and take a good look at what's happening. :)

Comment: "There's no genitive pronoun" - my grammar book defines 'Ihres' and 'meines' from the first sentences as pronouns without nouns(but with noun's suffixes).

Comment: @Alan: I'm not sure I understand your comment correctly, but what karoshi is saying is that "these examples contain pronouns, but they aren't in the genitive"

Comment: That's correct, but whether it's nominative, genitive etc. depends on its function in the sentence (the case). You're probably confused by the fact that a neuter pronoun looks like the corresponding genitive article/determiner, that is, they both are "meines"/"ihres" or whatever. As I said, I've seen the *pronoun* (but never the genitive article) written as "meins" instead of "meines".

Comment: Thanks karoshi. Just to sum up; a sample sentence with actual Genitive pronoun would be: "Das ist die Leine mein(e)s Hundes.", the ones I have are Nominativ Neutrum.

Comment: @Alan no, that's still a possessive determiner (or article as it's sometimes called), since it's followed by a name, and it's only "meines", never "meins". I'm looking for an actual usage case of a genitive pronoun. I'll post it here as soon as I have it.

Comment: @Alan so taken from http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de/lernen.php?menu_id=77#deklination, to get a genitive pronoun you'd do something like "Das ist die Leine meines Hundes. Wie ist die Leine deines?" and here the "deines" replaces "deines Hundes". In practice, I suspect in normal speech people would just say "Wie ist die Leine von deinem?" or even avoid the construction altogether and just say "deines Hundes" or "von deinem Hund".

Answer (score 1):

WARNING: This was the original answer, which I see now is wrong. The comments bellow the answer lead to that conclusion.

---

(You could restate the first as:

> – Wem gehört dieses Buch?
>   – Ist es *Ihr Buch*, Frau Schmidt?
>   – Ja, es ist meines.

if you wouldn't mind to repeat the noun *Buch*. That's what genitive there does:  it's avoiding repetition. Otherwise, you say it in nominative.

Other viewpoint would be that, since possessive pronouns already, well, imply possession, you don't need an additional genitive. You do the same in English, actually. Trying to state the second as you say, would be the same mistake as saying "That album is *of hers*".)

Comment: Thanks for both answers. I get it now. Regarding the second paragraph: so genitive is used with possessive pronouns only when a noun is not present? When there is a noun we use either nominativ, dativ or akk.?

Comment: Careful: there isn't a genitive in these sentences... all there is is a possessive pronoun in the nominative case.

Comment: @Mac mh, I have my doubts. That is, *ihres* appear in the [tables of declension](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/mein) both as pronoun for Nominative Neutrum and for Gen. Neutr. or Masc. Well, you mean, if we change the noun *Buch* into *Wagen*, then *ihres* should be changed into *ihrer*? (it's a real question - I'm no longer sure).

Comment: "Es ist ihr Wagen, es ist ihrer".

Comment: @c.p. Apparently our thoughts raced along the same track there for a second: see my comment on the other question... :)

Comment: @Mac Ok, ich sehe du hast Recht.

Comment: The answer is maybe not entirely correct but through analyzing it, the comments and other answers I have actually understood what is happening in my sentences.

Comment: @Mac I've got my doubts if any of us is entirely correct. I think it's a personal pronoun, not a possessive pronoun at all.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct.

In 1) "Ihres" substitues "ihr Buch". So 1) becomes "Ist es es ihr Buch, Frau Schmidt? Ja, es ist mein Buch." in the long version.

In 2), if you substite "ihr Album" accordingly, you get "Ja, das ist ihres."

Comment: You may want to look again - both are "Possessivpronomen" and "ihr" (not "ihres") functions as a "Possessivartikel": http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Poss1.html